# Custom styling individual letters

Tags: html, css

I wanted to ask, if there is a way to style clean way ( without using for example `<span></span>` ) for each sign, numbers ?

In attachment some example. We can see, let's say "flip clock" effect.

I found some plugins as flipclock, but i don't need any JS for animations, etc...

I just need to style number, by adding some background to every sign...

[image: example]

Answer (score 3):

Nope, you can only select the first letter with `::first-letter`.

You would have to use `span` elements to wrap the characters.

Answer (score 2):

You can not style every letter individually, without chaniging your markup.
You need to have a element to style around every letter.

For example:

```css
span {
  position: relative;
  
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1em;
  padding: 0.25em 0;
  background: #333;
  border-radius: 5px;
  
  font-size: 50px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

span::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0.2em;
  right: 0.2em;
  border-bottom: 0.2em solid #DDD;
}
```

```html
<span>1</span>
<span>0</span>
<span>0</span>
<span>0</span>
<span>0</span>
```

Comment: Yes, looks like only way.

Comment: The only solution without a markup, is to add a repeated background on your container. For this solution work you have to have a monospace font and play with `letter-spacing`

Comment: Yes, absolutely. The only option is to go for a fixed width font. Then you can do whatever you want with backgrounds

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand the question completely , but assuming a few things this might help.

```css
span
{
  display:inline-block;
  height:80px;
  width:50px;
  font-size:40px;
  
}
.first
{
  
  color:blue;
  background:#ccc;
}

.second
{
  color:red;
  background:#f1f1f1;
}
.fifth
{
  color:white;
  background:red;
}
.third
{
  color:green;
  background:#666;
}
.fourth
{
  color:yellow;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<span class="first">1</span>
<span class="second">1</span>
<span class="third">1</span>
<span class="fourth">1</span>
<span class="fifth">1</span>
```

## OR

if you are trying to edit the existing code you can use [n-th child selector](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)
in css to do this if you know the parent `div` name.

```
.parentdiv:nth-child(2) {
    background: #ff0000; // applies this style to second element
}
```

Comment: The OP wants to use just one element, like `p` - without having `span` for every character.

Comment: You understand good :) But i was asking for solution without separating each number. But this may be impossible...

Comment: You cannot apply styles in parts to a division. This will be impossible. Check the edited answer if that would suffice. You need to access each one of them if you want to access them individually. If you want to apply styles altogether then you can simple use `<span>` to style it.

Comment: best solution is with :after, as i dont know exact number - number may be diffrent.

Answer (score 0):

Add this style

```
<style>
.first{
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 50px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    position: relative;
}
.row {
    background: #fff;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1px;
    width: 35px;
    left: 5px;
    height: 10px;
}
</style>
```

Add this HTML code

```
<span class="first">1<span class="row"></span></span>
```

I hope this will help you.... :) 
Demo https://jsfiddle.net/ashvin0999/3ee1waun/